# Z3 Prover: Equivalent to Python Datatype in the C++ API

Tags: c++, z3, z3py

Is there an equivalent to the Python Datatype() API for C++?

For example in Python you can do:

```
>>> List = Datatype('List')
>>> List.declare('cons', ('car', IntSort()), ('cdr', List))
>>> List.declare('nil')
>>> List = List.create()
>>> # List is now a Z3 declaration
>>> List.nil
nil
>>> List.cons(10, List.nil)
cons(10, nil)
>>> List.cons(10, List.nil).sort()
List
>>> cons = List.cons
>>> nil  = List.nil
>>> car  = List.car
>>> cdr  = List.cdr
>>> n = cons(1, cons(0, nil))
>>> n
cons(1, cons(0, nil))
>>> simplify(cdr(n))
cons(0, nil)
>>> simplify(car(n))
1
```

How to declare such algebraic datatypes using the C++ API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In general, everything you can do from the Python API (and other APIs), you can do from C/C++. The function you're looking for is called `Z3_mk_datatype`. See:

https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/group__capi.html#ga34875df69093aca24de67ae71542b1b0

for details.

Note that the C/C++ APIs are much lower level, so while possible to do so, I'd strongly recommend against using these APIs unless you've a requirement that forces you to use C/C++.

Comment: Thanks @alias I did come across this, but the signature is different from that available in Python, it needed extra work to build and provide constructors :'), whereas Python API is much simpler.

Comment: That's correct. The C/C++ API is much lower level, so you have to stitch all of those parts together yourself to give you what Python provides. (Also keep in mind that you have to manage memory yourself as well, i.e., reference counting, so you don't have any leaks.) This is why most people program using a higher-level API like that provided by Python.